# Controlling filenames while downloading images from a url list using parallel and wget using linux terminal

Tags: linux, download, wget, gnu-parallel

I have a URL list of images in `urls.txt` file, and would like to download them using as follows on the Linux terminal:

```
cat urls.txt | parallel --gnu "wget {}"
```

However, the above command downloads the images with the names existing on the URL text. I would like to download them with the index name of the line. For example,

```
url0 -> 0.jpg
url1 -> 1.jpg
...
urln -> n.jpg
```

How should I modify the command?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
cat urls.txt | parallel --gnu wget {} -O {#}.jpg
```